# VBA/Excel - Change audio track number, depending on track version

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm attempting to add each track number of the 'main track'. As you can see there are alternate versions that need the main track number listed in column R.

It would be great if column R could populate itself with the correct track number.

Any advice on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Column Layout in Excel]

Comment: Are you open to the idea of using a formula?

Comment: Yes, please let me know what you would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula that would achieve this would be:

```
=IF(Q2="Y","",IF(Q1="Y",P1,R1))
```

This should be placed in R2 and copied down.